# How to generate the suggestion lines to align the rectangles along with group of other rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I have a grid-based system, think of it as a photoshop, There are draggable blocks in the system which can be moved around. I want to provide the **lines of suggestion where the user can drop** the block so that it is aligned with the appropriate block.

Here, in the video, **the blue lines** are being generated by such an algorithm. **What is the name of this algorithm?**

[image: Example PandaDoc]

Example: from PandaDoc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what algorithm is used here.
But I created a simple demo of the same using [P5.js](https://p5js.org/get-started/) library.

The main logic is to consider each element a box and match it corners with the coordinates of the mouse.

```js
const wOffset = draggableBox.w /2 ;
    const hOffset = draggableBox.h / 2;
    const currentPosX = mouseX - wOffset;
    const currentPosY = mouseY - hOffset;

    for(let i = 0; i<boxes.length ; i++){
        stroke(boxes[i].color_);
        noFill();
        rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].w, boxes[i].h);
        
        let diff = abs(currentPosX - boxes[i].x);
        if(diff < 7){
            stroke(255);
            strokeWeight(2);
            line(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].x, currentPosY);
        }

        diff = abs(currentPosY - boxes[i].y);
        if(diff < 7){
            stroke(255);
            strokeWeight(2);
            line(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, currentPosX, boxes[i].y);
        }

        diff = abs(currentPosX - (boxes[i].x + boxes[i].w));
        if(diff < 7){
            stroke(255);
            strokeWeight(2);
            line((boxes[i].x + boxes[i].w), boxes[i].y, (boxes[i].x + boxes[i].w), currentPosY);
        }

        diff = abs(currentPosX - (boxes[i].x + boxes[i].w/2));
        if(diff < 7){
            stroke(255);
            strokeWeight(2);
            line((boxes[i].x + boxes[i].w /2), boxes[i].y, (boxes[i].x + boxes[i].w /2), currentPosY);
        }

        diff = abs(currentPosY - (boxes[i].y + boxes[i].h));
        if(diff < 7){
            stroke(255);
            strokeWeight(2);
            line(boxes[i].x, (boxes[i].y + boxes[i].h), currentPosX, (boxes[i].y + boxes[i].h));
        }

        diff = abs(currentPosY - (boxes[i].y + boxes[i].h / 2));
        if(diff < 7){
            stroke(255);
            strokeWeight(2);
            line(boxes[i].x, (boxes[i].y + boxes[i].h / 2), currentPosX, (boxes[i].y + boxes[i].h / 2));
        }
    }

    let diff = abs(currentPosX - width / 2);
    if(diff < 1.5){
        stroke(MOUSE_LINE_COLOR);
        line(currentPosX, 0, currentPosX, currentPosY);
    }
    diff = abs(currentPosY - height / 2);
    if(diff < 1.5) {
        stroke(MOUSE_LINE_COLOR);
        line(0, currentPosY, currentPosX, currentPosY);
    }

    stroke(color(255, 0, 0));
    rect(mouseX - wOffset, mouseY - hOffset, draggableBox.w, draggableBox.h);
    // line(0, mouseY, 600, mouseY);
```

You can find my [github gist here](https://gist.github.com/akay25/258c44b6b2f23d420aaaa4d07f59948d).

Comment: Thank you @AMI, this was really helpful, but the gist is not covering all use cases, I'm not currently accepting this as solution, as there must be a name of the algorithm I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah yes, on checking I realised that cases from right and bottom edge are missing.